# Angular.js DI with (ES6) classes and inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

Background, current implementation of classes/modules in our app is common.js and CoffeeScript classes. I'm desperately looking for a solution to work with ES6 or TypeScript, but the problem remains.

How to do DI with class inheritance using Angular-1.x?

Given the code:

```
// SuperService.js
class SuperService {
  constructor($http, $q, $etc) {
    // Implementation is not important ...  
  }   
}
export { SubService }

// SubService.js
import { SuperService } from './SuperService';
class SubService extends SuperService {
  constructor($more, $di, $things, $here) {
    // Implementation is not important ... 
    // // // // // // // // // // 
    // Problem exists here ... //
    // // // // // // // // // //
    super($we, $need, $all, $the, $super, \
          $class, $di, $things, $every, $time, $we, \
          $inherit, $from, $it)
  }
}
export { SubService }
```

Must one, in the `SubService` here redefine all the parent DI requirements in order to successfully call `super()`?

We're presently doing something akin to the following:

```
// CoffeeScript                              // Javascript
app.factory "subService", (Service) ->       app.factory("subService", function(Service) {
  SubService = () ->                           var SubService;
    Service.call(@)                            SubService = function() {
    @                                            Service.call(this);
                                                 return this;
  # Overwrite some stuff on the "Service"      };
  Service::basepath = "/environments"          Service.prototype.basepath = "/environments";
  Service::model = Environment                 Service.prototype.model = Environment;
                                               return new SubService();
  new SubService()                           });
```

Which is also less than ideal, aside from being ugly.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  We're also approaching it in a similar fashion but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Exactly for this reason, my team hasn't made the switch to ES6 for our angular things yet, we're hoping that this will somehow be addressed in the typescript move in ng-2.0, but we're not seeing anything that solves this yet.

Comment: As in most other places too, in AngularJS I think its easier and more readable to use composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

*it's not ES6 (it's ES7), but it just might float your boat*

I would look into [angular-decorators](https://github.com/MikeRyan52/angular-decorators) by [MikeRyan52](https://github.com/MikeRyan52).

He's put together an `@inject` decorator that works as follows:

```
@inject('$http', '$rootScope')
class SomeClass {
  constructor($http, $rootScope) {

  }
}

@inject('$q')
class SubClass extends SomeClass {
  constructor($q, ...parentDependencies) { /** parent dependencies caught with a rest parameter **/
    super(...parentDependencies);
  }
}
```

[the implementation of @inject](https://github.com/MikeRyan52/angular-decorators/blob/master/src/decorators/inject.js)

Comment: great, thanks for that tip, I think when you start backporting angular2 features back to angular one, it might be better to invest the time to upgrade :) but still, awesome to see a proof of concept, and have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

add this at the very bottom of SubService.js

```
SubService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', '$etc', '$more', '$di', '$things', '$here'];
```